# Better practise: Reset array and re-add all items or search through array and remove unnecessary ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, performance

I have a list of HTML elements (li's) in a container (ul) which get added after the user selects an item from a full list. There are different categories and each category has corresponding "items".
Example:

```
<!--Clicking on an item adds it to the user_selection_list below-->
 <ul class="full_list">
   <li data-category="A" data-item="1">test1</li>
   <li data-category="A" data-item="2">test2</li>
   <li data-category="A" data-item="3">test3</li>
   <li data-category="A" data-item="4">test4</li>

   <li data-category="B" data-item="1">test1</li>
   <li data-category="B" data-item="2">test2</li>

   <li data-category="C" data-item="1">test1</li>
   <li data-category="C" data-item="2">test2</li>
   <li data-category="C" data-item="3">test3</li>
   <li data-category="C" data-item="4">test4</li>
</ul>

<!--Items that were selected-->
<ul class="user_selection_list">
  <li data-category="A" data-item="1">test1</li>
  <li data-category="A" data-item="2">test2</li>
  <li data-category="A" data-item="4">test4</li>

  <li data-category="B" data-item="1">test1</li>
  <li data-category="B" data-item="2">test2</li>

  <li data-category="C" data-item="3">test3</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="execute()">exec</button>
```

Ultimately what i want in the end is to create a json objects array via Javascript (or jquery) as such:

```
let data_json = [
  {"category" : A, "items": [1,2,4]},
  {"category" : B, "items": [1,2]},
  {"category" : C, "items": [3]}
]
```

Which of the following methods maybe the most efficient assuming that there could be about 1-100 selections in the "user_selection_list" list:

## Method A:

1. Everytime a user selects an "li" from the full_list, add it to the "user_selection_list" (if it already exists > remove it)
2. Clear data_json
3. Loop through "user_selection_list" and add each item to a temp JSON structure as such:

   let temp_data_json = [
   {"category": "A", "item": "1"},
   {"category": "A", "item": "2"},
   {"category": "A", "item": "4"},
   {"category": "B", "item": "1"},
   {"category": "B", "item": "2"},
   {"category": "C", "item": "3"}]
4. When the user presses the EXEC button, then i loop through each item in the temp structure and organise by categories to achieve data_json.

I feel that by just adding each item without cateorising them at first into a temp_data_json, it will be faster to add them and THEN we can categorise them after a button press.
By clearing the JSON data and then re-adding, we make sure that we have a perfectly synced list in "user_selection_list" and data_json

## Method B:

1. Everytime a user selects an "li" from the full_list, add it to the "user_selection_list" (if it exists already > remove it)
2. Clear data_json
3. Loop through each item in the "user_selection_list" and organise by categories immediatey to achieve data_json. This will involve checking each item in the "user_selection_list" to see what category it belongs to, then add it to its corresponding category in the json.
4. When they press the EXEC button, the data will already be structured

By clearing the JSON data and then re-adding, we make sure that we have a perfectly synced list in "user_selection_list" and data_json

## Method C (no clear but search and remove):

1. Everytime a user selects an "li" from the full_list, add it to the "user_selection_list" (if it exists already > remove it)
2. At the same time, loop through each item data_json, check to see if the item exists in the corresponding category. If the category doesnt exist > create it and add the item. If the category does exist and the item doesnt exist > add item to existing category.If neither exist > create the category & the item.
3. When they press the EXEC button, the data will already be structured

This way I feel we are not "syncing" but maintaining two lists (the "user_selection_list" and the data_json) but I do not know whether it is more effiencient to **simply clear the data_json list and re-add all items** OR **search the data_json and add/remove when necessary**.

Comment: Have you tried with a profiler?

Comment: There’s no json here.

Comment: What about, when user selects a li, do step 1 as you have laid out.  When a user presses execute, generate your data structure from the contents of the user selection list.